# Number format and index out of bound.

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-arrayadapter

Java android is complain about how to make parse Integer from String array. My string array has almost 300 numbers. When I make the same code but parse it as float, the code works fine I don't want the decimal values. I just need the number itself. It is throwing  **java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "97.601006"**. Would you mind to tell me what should I do. I also have one more question. I want to have the position/index of the peak value (Not the value itself) from my algorithm **findPeaks**. When I do **peaks.get(i)**  the system is also crashing and says **IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 24, size is 1**
Thanks in advance.

```
 String Adata = String.valueOf(stringBuilder);

            String dataArray[];
            dataArray = Adata.split("\\s+");
            Log.i("TAG", "Size of dataArray: " + dataArray.length);
            List String_TO_List = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int lastLength = dataArray.length - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < lastLength; i++) {
                //the console pointed at this line with number format exception
                int dataOfArray = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[i]);
                if (dataOfArray > 170) {
                    String_TO_List.add(dataOfArray);
                }
            }
            Log.i("TAG", "Size of list: " + String_TO_List.size());
            List<Integer> List_Of_Peaks = findPeaks(String_TO_List);

            Log.i(TAG, "Peaks" + List_Of_Peaks);
            Peaks_num.setText(String.valueOf(List_Of_Peaks));




           //my algorithm to find the peaks.
 ArrayList<Float> peaks = new ArrayList<Float>();
    float x1_n_ref = 0;
    int alpha = 0; //0=down, 1=up.
    int size = points.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i+=4) {
        float IndexValues = points.get(i);
        float delta = x1_n_ref - IndexValues;

        if ( delta < 0) {
            x1_n_ref = IndexValues;
            alpha = 1;
        } else if (alpha == 1 && delta > 0) {
            peaks.add(x1_n_ref);
              // here the system complain with Index exception. I want to know the poition or the index of the peak value so I can pass it to setText or Toast message.
              peaks.get(i);
              Log.i("TAG", "peak added: " + x1_n_ref);
            alpha = 0;
        } else if (alpha == 0 && delta > 0) {
            x1_n_ref = IndexValues ;
        }

        //}

    }

    return peaks;
}
```

Comment: Use Double.parseDouble()  and then use casting to convert to int. `int dataOfArray = (int) Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i]);`

Comment: And you might want to check for (int i = 0; i < size; i+=4)... The i+=4 is suspicious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Math.round(). It rounds a floating value to an integer. To round your value you have to parse it from String to double at first.
Replace your line

```
int dataOfArray = Integer.parseInt(dataArray[i]);
```

with

```
int dataOfArray = Math.round(Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i]));
```

Your example with "97.601006" will result in 98.

Comment: Great, your answers are helpful. But how about the **praks.add(i)** why it is throwing an exception. I want to know the position of the peak.

Comment: peaks.get(i); Look at the variable i. It is not the index of your peaks array. It is the index of your points array. Additional the statement peaks.get(i); does nothing.

Comment: so how come I can get the index of the peaks,

Comment: change from peaks.get(i) to peaks.add(i)?

Comment: peaks.add(x1_n_ref); is x1_n_ref not the peak value itself?

Comment: oh I did both already and same error exception is showing. and yes **peaks.add(x1_n_ref)** is the value of each peak I find during the iteration. It that the only way I can get the position of the peak? I mean by peaks.add(i). or is there alternative solution.